# How to rotate a single image around a remote point

Tags: java

I'm developing a tube shooter-esque game in java that simulates 3D without actually using any 3D libraries. Right now I have a player-controlled ship that rotates around the center point of the screen, using (in this case, for moving right).

```
    angle += 0.1;
    x = Math.cos(angle) * radius + cX;
    y = Math.sin(angle) * radius + cY;
```

Where `angle` is the placement in relation to the center point (ex. 270 is directly under the center), `x` and `y` are the current ship position, `radius` is the distance from the center, and `cX` and `cY` are the center point's location.

Right now revolving around the point works smoothly, but I'm not sure how to handle rotating the actual ship to always point towards the center. I've looked around a lot online but can't figure out how an individual `Image` (or if that doesn't work, an array of `drawLines`) can be rotated without affecting other objects on the screen.

Long story short, how would one go about rotating an individual `Image` to constantly point towards a remote x,y location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is the `AffineTransform` class which is basically a matrix class in java. `Graphics2D` has a draw image variant which accepts an `AffineTransform` instance:

```
boolean java.awt.Graphics2D.drawImage(Image img, AffineTransform xform, ImageObserver obs)
```

To create a transform, you can use 2D matrix operations:

```
AffineTransform trans = new AffineTransform();
trans.translate(x, y);
trans.rotate(theta);
trans.scale(scalex, scaley);
etc...
```

Mind that the order is important, probably you will want to scale first, rotate and then traslate the image to the corresponding location. It should do fine.

Java has uses some 3D power to draw as fast as it can, it is faster than a software renderer, but quite far from native opengl.